# Export artifact (or RPM) from Jenkins to Jfrog artifacory

Tags: maven, rpm, artifactory, yum

I have a maven project which creates RPM upon build. Is there any plugin which I can export RPM to JFrog Artifacory?

Answer (score -1):

[Artifactory Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin)